# How to get the destination 'B' lat, long details and pass to my marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using Mapbox directions plugin and trying to achieve the following:
First thing I have added two points on map 'A' and 'B' using mapbox directions. The route will be displaying after adding the points. 
When I click on a button, should call a follow function and would like my marker 'myMovingMarker3' should travel to destination 'B's lattitude and longitude.
Also there is another function called locate which get the currentlattitude and currentlongitude for the 'myMovingMarker3', how to call locate function inside follow function.

```
var newLat;
var newLng;
var newdestn = [];


function followNew(){   
var marker = L.mapbox.directions.inputControl.document.getElementById("mapbox-directions-destination-input").addTo(map);
marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
 var coords = e.target.getLatLng();
 var newLat = coords.lat;
 var newLng = coords.lng;   
 return {lat: newLat, lon: newLng};

});

}

followNew();

// This is the follow() function, which will be invoked by button;
function follow(){
    alert("Helloooo");  
    newdestn = followNew();
    alert(newLat+" and "+newLng);   
    var myMovingMarker3 = L.Marker.movingMarker([[currentLatitude, currentLongitude],[newLat, newLng],],[37000],{icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-color': '#ff9933'})}).addTo(map);
    myMovingMarker3.start();    
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle. This will clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have added the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2077w4r8/20/